# Creating hyperlink in xpages mail

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I using profile document to store current database path and database name

I try to write it a hyperlink to get the document. I not sure which part is wrong, it doesn't give the link. It just a plaintext.

[image]

hyperlink code

```
stream.writeText("<p>For select this document, please click <a href='http://"+web+"/"+dname.replace(/(\\)/g, "/")+"/"+
"Request_Form.xsp?databaseName="+server+"!!"+
dname+"&documentId="+
document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()+
"&action=editDocument'>here</a></P>")
```

below is full code of sending email

[image]

```
var setdoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("System Setting", "");

var server = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDBSvr");
var dname = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDbPath");
var web = setdoc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress");

var maildoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "REQUEST FOR REGISTER AN EMAIL");
session.setConvertMime(false);
var stream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText("<html><body>");

stream.writeText("<p>Dear " + document1.getItemValueString("Dep_rev") + ",</p>");
stream.writeText('<P>Kindly review this request by '+document1.getItemValueString('Name')+" on "+I18n.toString(@Today(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')+ ",</p>");

stream.writeText("<p>For select this document, please click <a href='http://"+web+"/"+dname.replace(/(\\)/g, "/")+"/"+
"Request_Form.xsp?databaseName="+server+"!!"+
dname+"&documentId="+
document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()+
"&action=editDocument'>here</a></P>")

stream.writeText("<p>Or</p>");

//stream.writeText("<p>Select this view</p>");

stream.writeText("</body></html>");
var body = maildoc.createMIMEEntity("Body");
body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 1725);
stream.close();
maildoc.closeMIMEEntities(true);
session.setConvertMime(true);

maildoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo",document1.getItemValueString("Dep_rev"));     
//maildoc.replaceItemValue("CopyTo", lsdoc.getItemValueString("Email"));        
//maildoc.replaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo", oasentmail);
maildoc.send();
```

[image]

Comment: One bit of advice. Profile documents get cached, as I found when developing XPages Help Application for OpenNTF. Expect to hit problems with values not retrieved correctly. I'm not aware of an easy way to troubleshoot or fix the caching issues, which is why I abandoned that approach.

Comment: Did you check if the displayed content is the HTML that you created? Maybe the mail client you use modifies the content before it's displayed to you, because even if the link you create would not be appropriate that client should definitely indicate that "here" is a hyperlink...

Comment: I check on my lotus client is display a link. while i using Chrome browser it doesn't not show it as a link~

Comment: Btw: If the link or url parameters contain special characters you need not forget to escape both. First you have to (url-)escape/encode the url parameters when generating the url and afterwards you have to (html-)escape the full url before writing it into the href attribute.

Comment: ok. will try it later. Thanks for the suggestion~

Comment: In Chrome, like most other browsers, you can have a look at the underlying html code via the "Inspect" function. For example, when the mail gets displayed right-click on "here" (where the link should be) and select "Inspect", or "Inspect element". A panel will open showing you the surrounding html. This way you can check how your original html has been modified and why the link is not displayed or working.

Comment: I use another way to do it, now working already : stream.writeText("<p> Select document, please click "+"<a href='http://"+web+"/"+
database.getServer()+"!!"+
XSPUrl.encodeParameter(dname, "UTF-8") +
"/"+"Request_Form.xsp?databaseName="+server+"!!"+
XSPUrl.encodeParameter(dname,"UTF-8") +
"&documentId="+document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()+
"&action=editDocument'>here</a></p>")